# Play2.0: Restart on fatal error?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I use playframework 2.0.4 with scala.
I deploy the app using "play dist" and then start it with the "./start" script.

Recently, I had the case that my production instance didn't have enough memory and crashed. I got an error

```
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.promises-dispatcher-456] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
```

and the play process was dead.

Is there a way to disable akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error and set it to restart the play application when crashing? It's a production environment and a not-running application isn't really helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think that if the application crashes like this, the Akka environment might be in an inconsistent state and attempting to salvage it would probably not work.

Instead I'd look into [process supervision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Supervision) with tools such as [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)